# How to include a XML Tag with in the SOAP Response

Tags: java, spring, api, web-services, soap

In my current soap API,the response is coming in single line as a string. I need to split the response in three part in xml format.

For eg:- current scenario
<return>Unique~status~data</return>
Required below format

return>

1. <unique>1233</unique>
2. <status>success</status>
3. <data>this is the data</data>
   </return>

Please suggest.Thanks